# Connecting to MQ using CCDT JSON from Websphere

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I have IBM MQ running in one docker container and in another container I have IBM Websphere running. From Websphere I am trying to create QCF using CCDT connection method. I have copied CCDT file inside /tmp folder of Websphere container, when I test the connection I get the error:

```
A connection could not be made to IBM MQ for the following reason: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2278' ('MQRC_CLIENT_CONN_ERROR').*
```

I am able to connect from MQ Explorer using the same CCDT file.

[image]

CCDT JSON sample used:

```
{
     "channel":
          [
               {
                    "connectionManagement":
                    {
                         "sharingConversations": 10,
                         "defaultReconnect": "no",
                         "heartbeatInterval": 10,
                         "keepAliveInterval": -1
                },
                "general":
                {
                        "description": "Client Channel Definition",
                        "maximumMessageLength": 104857600
                },
                "name": "CHANNEL1",
                "clientConnection":
                {
                    "connection":
                    [
                        {
                            "host": "IP",
                            "port": port
                        }
                    ],
                "queueManager": "QMNAME"
                },
                "type": "clientConnection"
            }
          ]
}
```

Comment: Which version of WAS are you using?

Comment: WAS 9.0.5.8-1 and WAS MQ 9.2.0-2

Comment: As long as you are using 9.2 RA with WAS the JSON CCDT should work.   Can you please provide the json in your question (sanitized if required) and please look in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG file to see if there is a corresponding error and post it as well.

Comment: sure. nothing in the log file. As per IBM 9.0.5.8 version uses 9.1.0.7 version of resource adapter. Here is the sample JSON added in OP. –

Comment: Sorry i thought you by "WAS MQ 9.2.0-2" that you had manually added the 9 2.0.2 RA to WAS.  JSON CCDT was not added until 9.2 so you won't be able to use it with a 9.1.0.7 RA.  Also note that the name of the queue manager product has been "IBM MQ" since 8.0, "Websphere MQ" was the name from 5.3 - 7.5, 5.2 and lower were "MQSeries".  Your only options are to use a binary CCDT or add/installed the 9.2 RA (rar) for was to use instead of the builtin 9.1.0.7.  9.2.0.4 is the latest and you can download the java-all package to obtain the rar file.

Comment: Thanks it worked with RA 9.2.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON CCDT support was not added to IBM MQ until 9.2 LTS.  You won't be able to use it with a 9.1.0.7 RA.

Your only options are to use a binary CCDT or add/installed the 9.2 RA (rar) for WAS to use instead of the builtin 9.1.0.7 RA.

9.2.0.4 is the latest and you can download the java-all package to obtain the rar file.